# How to show if two objects are moving away in 3D space

Tags: math, 3d, game-engine, game-physics

I am working on a yet another 3d game engine and have following Problem. In order to improve Performance I want to check if two Objects are coming closer or moving away from each other. Only if they are coming closer to each other collision detection should happen.

At the moment the code calculates the current distance using the positions of both Objects. Then moves both positions about the velocity vector and calculates the expected distance. etc.

```
public class Model{

    public boolean isApproaching(Model model) {
        float [] otherPosition = model.getPosition();
        float [] otherVelocity = model.getVelocity();
        double currentDistance = Math.pow(this.position[0] - otherPosition[0], 2)
                                + Math.pow(this.position[1] - otherPosition[1], 2)
                                + Math.pow(this.position[2] - otherPosition[2], 2);
        double expectedDistance = Math.pow(this.position[0] + this.velocityVector[0]/1000 - otherPosition[0] - otherVelocity[0]/1000, 2)
                                + Math.pow(this.position[1] + this.velocityVector[1]/1000 - otherPosition[1] - otherVelocity[1]/1000, 2)
                                + Math.pow(this.position[2] + this.velocityVector[2]/1000 - otherPosition[2] - otherVelocity[2]/1000, 2);
        if(currentDistance < expectedDistance)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

As you can see in the Picture it does not work for fast moving objects. Is there any good way to show if two points are moving towards each other?

[image]

Comment: I would try using the cross product of their direction vectors. Either that or solve for their intersection point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the two straight line trajectories, there's a unique time when they're going to be closest, which may have been in the past.  If it's in the past then it means that the objects are moving away from each other, but if its in the future it means that they're moving closer together.  But even it they're moving closer together, I would guess that knowing how soon is the information that you need, so that you can schedule when to worry about it.  This methodology should cater for both slow moving and fast moving objects.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using the `/1000` versus any other value for some unstated reason that may negate the following.

By changing this scale factor you get better detection with a fast object.  Perform your same `isApproaching()` calculation except with a `/(1000*N)` instead of `/1000`.  You will then has N times better sensitivity to know if they are approaching or not.

Comment: The 1000 is some random value and supposed to "slow down" both objects to avoid case 2. Your solution sounds better. Thanks.

Comment: Having worked in Air Traffic Control provides some insight.  You want to improve performance, why not use integer math or only use `double` and avoid `float` to double conversion time? @Blender cross-product idea is good too.